# I have some error in C# Drawing Application?

Tags: c#, system.drawing

i am using visual studio 2010 for making a Drawing Application but the problem is when i try to compile the program it says

1)The type name 'DrawingBoard' does not exist in the type 'DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard' **line 33**

2)The type name 'Toolbox' does not exist in the type 'DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard' **line 34**

3)An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard.EditOption.get' **line 74**

the code of this program is below i have pointed the errors with the word problem. i would be very Thankful if you help me.

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace DrawingBoard
{
    partial class WinForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.splitContainerMain = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
            this.drawingBoard = new DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard();//problem
            this.toolBox = new DrawingBoard.Toolbox.ToolBox();//problem
            this.splitContainerMain.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainerMain.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainerMain.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // splitContainerMain
            // 
            this.splitContainerMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.splitContainerMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.splitContainerMain.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.splitContainerMain.Name = "splitContainerMain";
            // 
            // splitContainerMain.Panel1
            // 
            this.splitContainerMain.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.drawingBoard);
            // 
            // splitContainerMain.Panel2
            // 
            this.splitContainerMain.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.toolBox);
            this.splitContainerMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(853, 553);
            this.splitContainerMain.SplitterDistance = 532;
            this.splitContainerMain.SplitterWidth = 3;
            this.splitContainerMain.TabIndex = 37;
            // 
            // drawingBoard
            // 
            this.drawingBoard.AllowDrop = true;
            this.drawingBoard.AutoScroll = true;
            this.drawingBoard.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.drawingBoard.BackgroundImageAlpha = ((byte)(255));
            this.drawingBoard.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.drawingBoard.BackgroundImageX = 0;
            this.drawingBoard.BackgroundImageY = 0;
            this.drawingBoard.BoundedCanvasHeight = 1140;
            this.drawingBoard.BoundedCanvasWidth = 810;
            this.drawingBoard.CanvasOriginX = 0;
            this.drawingBoard.CanvasOriginY = 0;
            this.drawingBoard.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.Default;
            this.drawingBoard.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.drawingBoard.EditOption = DrawingBoard.EditOption.Select; //problem
            this.drawingBoard.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gainsboro;
            this.drawingBoard.GridSize = 0;
            this.drawingBoard.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Default;
            this.drawingBoard.IsBoundedCanvas = true;
            this.drawingBoard.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.drawingBoard.Name = "drawingBoard";
            this.drawingBoard.PaperOutsideColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(230)))), ((int)(((byte)(230)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.drawingBoard.ShowPaperOutside = true;
            this.drawingBoard.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(532, 553);
            this.drawingBoard.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            this.drawingBoard.StickyEditOption = true;
            this.drawingBoard.TabIndex = 3;
            this.drawingBoard.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            this.drawingBoard.Zoom = 1F;
            // 
            // toolBox
            // 
            this.toolBox.AutoSize = true;
            this.toolBox.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.toolBox.Drawingboard = null;
            this.toolBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.toolBox.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.toolBox.Name = "toolBox";
            this.toolBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(318, 553);
            this.toolBox.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // WinForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(853, 553);
            this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainerMain);
            this.Name = "WinForm";
            this.Text = "DrawingBoard";
            this.splitContainerMain.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.splitContainerMain.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.splitContainerMain.Panel2.PerformLayout();
            this.splitContainerMain.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainerMain;
        private DrawingBoard drawingBoard;
        private global::DrawingBoard.Toolbox.ToolBox toolBox;

    }
}
```

Comment: what lines are the errors on?

Comment: The errors on the indicated lines just mean that the compiler cannot find the `DrawingBoard` and the `ToolBox` class. Without knowing more about your project and the declarations of the respective classes, we cannot tell anything beyond that.

Comment: 1)The type name 'DrawingBoard' does not exist in the type 'DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard' line 33                                      2)The type name 'Toolbox' does not exist in the type 'DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard' line 34                                   3)An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard.EditOption.get' line 74

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a namespace issue and it looks like `DrawingBoard.DrawingBoard` is probably going to cause confusion. Try to rename your namespace to omit duplicate names. Use a format such as `Solution.Project.Module`.  In your case it could be `MySolution.DrawingBoard`.